# how to use keypad button multiple integer value input

Tags: keypad

I have been working on water flow sensor which measures volume then i need to restrict the amount of water which disperse from depend on the user input form the keypad so how can i store the input form the keypad into a variable.

Comment: Various tutorials about keypads can be found on the web. Have you tried one of these? What didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the keypad library, there is a command to read a key:

```
 myKeypad.getKey();
```

Store these keys in a (string) buffer, and after a certain key is pressed (e.g. #), parse the string buffer to retrieve the integer (with the c function `atoi`, see [here for a description](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-atoi-function/)).